# Android Studio Drop Down not Spinner

Tags: android

I'm making an android app with Android Studio and I was wondering if there was anything that will let the user click on a button and have more information about the button drop down and have it disappear if the user presses on the button again. I've tried Spinner and it seems like that was more of a navigation tool than what I'm looking for.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a textview under the button and show/hide it when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**Menus**

Menus are a common user interface component in many types of applications. To provide a familiar and consistent user experience, you should use the Menu APIs to present user actions and other options in your activities.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html